# wp_schedule_event in a class

Tags: plugin-development, wp-cron

This is my (stripped down) plugin, in OOP:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Cron Test
Plugin URI: http://www.mywebsite.com/
Description: Test
Version: 1.0
Requires at least: 3.0
*/

class CronTest {
  public function __construct() {
      if ( !wp_next_scheduled( 'dailyops' ) ) {
          wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'dailyops' );
      }
      add_action( 'dailyops', array($this, 'do_this_daily') );
  }

  function do_this_daily() {
          // do something every day
          error_log('daily');
  }
}

$cronTest = new CronTest();
```

Anyway, it's not working (do_this_daily() is never fired). I tried the same in a non-OOP plugin (not based on a class) and it works flawlessy. How can I make it work here, in a class?

EDIT: I replaced the initial portion of the code with a full (still minimal) plugin that can be tested.

Comment: Where you instanziate the class (`$class = new MyClass()`)?

Comment: Yes, at the end of the class I'm instantiating it (sorry I omitted it in the excerpt).

Comment: Usually I put `wp_schedule_event` inside an hooked function, but your code should work for me... Maybe the problem is in something not posted.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I replaced the example with a full example plugin that you can directly copy and paste to test it. It doesn't work :(

Comment: I copy and paste your code in my local test environment: it works perfectly.

Comment: Does it really write 'daily' in the error log, every day?

Comment: For semplicity I've used `_doing_it_wrong` wp function to write log (in my test environment wp_debug and wp_log are activated) and the log file is written correctly. I've seen it one time... to see if it works daily I should look again tomorrow...

Comment: I tried to install my test plugin on another WP installation and it works, so you must be right: the problem is elsewhere. Thank you so much... I'll write here when I discover :)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I discovered what was wrong: the webserver (a dedicated VPS) had a bad configuration of the hosted domain, so it was unable to "self contact" it, to call wp-cron.php .

I fixed it and now every scheduled job works, including this one :)